# Check success or failure in GitHub Actions step using actions/github-script

Tags: javascript, github, github-actions

I am using [`actions/github-script`](https://github.com/actions/github-script). I want to check from within the step that uses it it whether previous steps were successful however the following line is marked with error:

```
"color": "${{ success() && '#36a64f' || '#ecb22e' }}",
```

Is there a way to go about it? The specific step has the `if: always()` condition.

Comment: I don't think JS ternary operators are supported in YAML syntax of GitHub actions

Comment: Can you not use an env var for this? See https://github.com/actions/github-script?tab=readme-ov-file#use-env-as-input.

Comment: @IhebMar https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#example

Comment: Marked with _what_ error? Give a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling upon this in the future:

```
"color": "${{ job.status == 'success' && '#36a64f' || '#ecb22e' }}",
```